# Reusable sub-queries in projection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to refactor some code where a query is executed, then two sub-queries are inside the projection. It looks like:

`from product in context.Product
join ...
join ...
where ...
select new ProductReturn()
{
  ....,
  FileCount = (from ...),
  SomeOtherCount = (from ...)
}`

The subqueries used to be done after the LINQ query, in a loop (making two new SQL queries per product) but I folded them into the select, which worked fine.

But now I want to extract how the FileCount and SomeOtherCount are fetched into their own methods so that I don't have to duplicate these subqueries everywhere.

I basically copied the LINQ query, created a new method, typed `return` then pasted the query. I needed to add some missing parameters like the product and context and a semi-colon.

Then my new projection looks like:
`select new ProductReturn()
{
  ....,
  FileCount = GetFileCount(context, product),
  SomeOtherCount = GetSomeOtherCount(context, product)
});`

This compiles fine! However at run-time, I get an exception:
`A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.`

I imagine it's trying to execute my sub-query while it's still materializing the first query, which means even if it worked, it would've just done multiple SQL queries instead of one SQL query.

Is it possible to achieve what I'm trying to do, or do I need to copy-paste my sub-queries everywhere?

I tried changing my signature from
`private Expression<Func<Product, int>> GetFileCount(MyDbContext context, Product product)` to `private Expression<Func<Product, int>> GetFileCount(MyDbContext context, Product product)` as I've seen in some places while looking for an answer, but `GetFileCount` doesn't even compile:

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Product, int>>' to 'int'`

Comment: Hmm, the signature change didn't come through, they appear identical, but you could try using that change, but then perhaps try `FileCount = GetFileCount(context, product).Body` .

Comment: Sorry I should've specified that it's `GetFileCount` that doesn't compile - not where the function is called.

Comment: [LinqKIt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/#linqkitmicrosoftentityframeworkcore),, [NeinLinq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/#neinlinqentityframeworkcore), even AutoMapper or similar - you need a 3rd partly library which allows embedding expressions. Writing your own would require a lot of effort, basically reinventing and duplicating what these libraries do.

Comment: @IvanStoev ah ok, thanks. Disappointing :(